# How can I force Node.js to not show my login button when logged in and show it when logged out

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, navbar

When the user logs in, `req.session.loggedin` changes to `true` so I want the buttons to disappear/appear when the variable changes to `true`. So in short I want to know how I can change the `loggedin` variable in pug-file from the Node.js file.

```
app.use(function(req, res, exit) {
    if(req.session.loggedin) {
        app.locals.loggedin = true;
    }
    else {
        app.locals.loggedin = false;
    }
    res.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/site/data')))
    exit();
})
```

And this is my .pug

```
            - var loggedin = false;
            li
              a(href='/') Home
            li
              a(href='/about') About
            li
              a(href='/contact') Contact
            if loggedin
              li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
            else     
              li
                a(href='/login') login
```

Don't be afraid to ask any questions if you've got them.

Comment: What you are doing is correct, i think you dont need the ```- var loggedin = flase``` in the pug file also you can do: ```app.locals.loggedin = req.session.loggedin``` beside the if statement on your app.use middleware

Comment: Well I can't give you any score but it worked. Sometimes I don't quite understand why things work and don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i can notice few issues in your code:

1. you dont need the if statement, `req.session.loggedin` should be boolean already
2. `app.locals.loggedin` should be `res.locals.loggedin`

your code should look like this:

Server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, exit) {
    
    res.locals.loggedin = req.session.loggedin;
    
    //Im not sure for what this line for therefore i leave it here.
    res.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/site/data')))

    exit();
})
```

Client:

```
            li
              a(href='/') Home
            li
              a(href='/about') About
            li
              a(href='/contact') Contact
            if loggedin
              li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
            else     
              li
                a(href='/login') login
```

---

*Somethings you need to make sure you have in your server-side code:*

---

Please dont forget to add this line (maybe its already there) in your post-login function

```
req.session.loggedin= true;
```

Also you need to make sure you have sessions middleware on your app.js

```
//The secret you might want to store in .env file.
const session = {
  secret: 'SUPER_SECRET_KEY',
  cookie: {},
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
};

//this will check if you are on development or production. and secure the cookie
//(session) if you are on production. (if you will not deploy your app its not a
//must to add it)
if (app.get("env") === "production") {
  // Serve secure cookies, requires HTTPS
  session.cookie.secure = true;
}
```

If not you need to `npm install express-session` and add `const session = require('express-session');` to the top of your app.js.

I guess you have it already, I just wanted to make sure.